# Azure CSP Subscription Usage information

Tags: azure

Does anyone know if it is possible to retrieve current usage information for a CSP subscription. I have looked at the Partner API but this only gives usage information at a aggregate level. I would like to have information per service running in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

The official microsoft docs provide to use the rest api or C# code for retrieving montly usage based information.

To call this api will give you a monthly usage. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/develop/get-a-subscriptions-resource-usage-information

```
GET https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/customers/{customer-tenant-id}/subscriptions/{id-for-subscription}/usagerecords/resources HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Accept: application/json
MS-RequestId: 65b26053-37d0-4303-9fd1-46ad8012bcb6
MS-CorrelationId: 47c36033-af5d-4457-80a4-512c1626fac4
```